# Alternative to $broadcast/$emit/$on in triggering events

Tags: angularjs

What is an alternative way in AngularJS to trigger events other than $broadcast/$emit/$on. If I will have too many event triggers between controllers and/or directives, I'm afraid this will lead to hard to trace spaghetti events. (Or could it be that too many events is a bad design after all?)

I heard using service/factory is the preferred way. Can someone give me an example how? Or are there other methods aside from service/factory?

Comment: Can you give examples of how you are using eventing? From your question it is unknown if you are overusing events.

Comment: For example, at the end of the function of controller/directive, say A, I want to invoke a function in another controller/directive, say B.

Comment: This is reasonable, directive A throws and event that directive B defines and listens to but is this really something that occurs on all of your directives?

Comment: For example if you have a Flyout directive and you want to resize it because the content inside it changes and some directive inside it throws a 'resizeFlyout' directive then that is fine.
On the other hand, if you are using eventing in every directive to state that it is done processing then you are not using events correctly.

Comment: Can you give me an example how to use service/factory to trigger events, instead of using $broadcast / $emit?

Comment: Services, factories, and providers would not handle eventing. They do not have a scope or a DOM element and thus are not the right place for that kind of thing.

Comment: Can you give any concrete example of what you are hoping to accomplish? Are you wanting to do something during initialization of the directives or during runtime when a directive detects a change? Can directive A only be used as a child or directive B, could it be used under directive C, can it be used by itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a event queue/event bus as a solution. Check out

http://jonathancreamer.com/an-angular-event-bus-with-postal-js/
and 
https://github.com/jseppi/angular-queue